# html5Shiv doesn't support input type number

Tags: html, input, html5shiv

I put following line into my head section.

```
<!--[if IE]>  
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>  
<![endif]-->
```

Opera and Chrome can show spinner in `<input type="number">` elements. But IE9 can not perform this action. As far as I know `html5shiv` or `shim` can give html5 power into IE. Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

html5shiv only enables styling of html5 elements/tags which are unknown to the browser. It does not add browser functionality.